# Reportlab add space between Balanced columns

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

For the balanced column in reportlab, I want to increase the spacing between the columns so that no text gets very close to each other and there is a clear separation between them.

In the user guide of reportlab, I couldn't find any solution for the same.

```py
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A4
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.platypus.flowables import BalancedColumns
from reportlab.platypus import Spacer, SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, PageBreak
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics




f = []
for i in range(10):
  f.append(Paragragh("Write some length paragraph here .."))
  f.append(Spacer(2*mm))

balancedCol = BalancedColumns(f, nCols=2, innerPadding=2*mm)

story = [balancedCol]
doc = SimpleDocTemplate('balancedCol.pdf')
doc.build(story)
```

The following image shows the space that I want to change or update.

[image]